# Click td, select radio button in jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Got a small problem with some very basic jQuery, I'd like to be able to click on a table cell, and then have it automatically select the radio button inside.

HTML:

```
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>
     1<br>
     <input type="radio" name="choice" value="1">
    </td>
    <td>
     2<br>
     <input type="radio" name="choice" value="2">
    </td>
    <td>
     3<br>
     <input type="radio" name="choice" value="3">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("td").click(function () {

  $(this).closest('input:radio').attr('checked',true);

 });
```

Any help would really be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Since the answers are already correct, I'll just add here that `.closest()` is for traversing **up** the DOM tree, e.g. getting the `<tr>` or the `<table>`, rather than down.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this selector:

```
$('input:radio', this).attr('checked', true);
```

Or using `find` method:

```
$(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
```

Here is how your code should look like:

```
$("td").click(function () {
   $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Comment: No need to wrap `this` in the jQuery constructor when used as a context, `$('input:radio', this)` is enough.

Comment: Thank you so much! One quick thing though, I'm changing the class when the radio button is selected, but this doesn't work when you click the cell, even though the radio button is selected? 
 $("td input[type=radio]").bind('change click', function () {

  $('td').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).parent('td').addClass('selected');

 });

Comment: @Box9: Updated to avoid any further confusion :)

Comment: @Nick: You should post that as another question :)

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked','checked');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try find instead of closest.

```
$(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked',true);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works perfectly

```
 $(function () {
        $('td').click(function () {

        var cell = $(this),
            state = cell.data('state') || 'first';

        switch (state) {
            case 'first':
                cell.data('state', 'second');
                cell.find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
                cell.find('input:radio').data('checked', true);
                cell.find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
                break;
            case 'second':
                cell.data('state', 'first');
                cell.find('input:radio').attr('checked', false);
                cell.find('input:radio').data('checked', false);
                cell.find('input:radio').prop('checked', false);
                break;
            default:

                break;
        }
    });
});
```