# Changing cell class on radio button change

Tags: jquery, radio-button

Huge thanks for the help in this thread - [Click td, select radio button in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625037/click-td-select-radio-button-in-jquery)

But now I'm having trouble that it won't change the class of the cell, even though I have binded the 'change' trigger in jQuery like so:

```
    $("td input[type=radio]").bind('change click', function () {

    $('td').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent('td').addClass('selected');

});

$("td").click(function () {

   $('input:radio', this).attr('checked', true);

});
```

Hope that makes sense. If you click the radio button, or move between them using the keyboard, the cell's class changes just fine. However if you trigger this by clicking the cell it doesn't change the class :(

Thanks

Comment: If the answers in the previous question ware helpful you should accept one.

Comment: I tried, but I haven't hit the 8 minute time limit yet, sorry! (2 minutes to go)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the `click` or `change` event will fire when you change attributes on an element. So you will have to trigger it manually. Also, I prefer to chain as much as possible, and in this case we can use the [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings) function. As the name suggests, it will select all the siblings (in your case all other `<td>` elements that have the *selected* class) of the current element.

Here you go:

```
$("td input:radio").bind('change click', function(){ 
    $(this).parent('td').addClass('selected').siblings('.selected').removeClass('selected');
});

$("td").click(function () {
    $('input:radio', this).attr('checked', 'checked').trigger('change');
});
```

Also, according to HTML specs, the `checked` attribute only have `checked` as valid value. However since most (if not all) browsers parses that attribute as a boolean, where empty or non-existing means false and any other value means true, it will work nevertheless but I personally prefer to follow the specs.

Comment: +1 (I hadn't thought about the [`trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) option. I'll note that `checked` is a Boolean though, so should be either `.attr('checked',true)` or not there at all (`.removeAttr('checked')`).

Comment: I've added a comment as to why I set the value to *checked*, I do the same with *selected* as well.

Comment: I do the same - probably unnecessarily

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
$("td input:radio").bind('change click', function() {

    $('td.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent('td').addClass('selected');

});
```

It seems to work: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m4p7m/1/).

Comment: Many thanks for this (and the JS Fiddle site, very useful!) but it still isn't working for me, hmm - must be some conflicting code! Will look into it.