# Make table cell clickable with jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a small Quiz on a webpage with a table of questions. In each row are two possible answers, each has its own radio button for selection. Now my Problem, i want to make the whole cell clickable and not just the Radio button.

This is the code i came up with, but it only works once per radio button. After the first click, i have to click multiple times to switch the selection.

```
jQuery(".clickable").click(function(event) {
    var x = jQuery("input", this).attr("checked");
    jQuery("input", this).attr("checked", !x);
    return false;
});
```

Here is a sample row

```html
<tr class="row_cls" id="quiz_row0">
    <td class="clickable" style="border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: middle;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">
        <label style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <input type="radio" style="height:20px; width:20px;" class="radio-form-control radio_input1" id="radio_input166" name="quiz_row0" value="Herausforderung" checked="checked"> 
            <span style="font-size: 20px;">Herausforderung</span>
        </label></td>
    <td class="clickable" style="border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: middle;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">
        <label style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <input type="radio" style="height:20px; width:20px;" class="radio-form-control radio_input1" id="radio_input118" name="quiz_row0" value="Macht/ Aufstieg" checked="checked"> 
            <span style="font-size: 20px;">Macht/ Aufstieg</span>
        </label></td>
</tr>
```

I would be really grateful for suggestions!

Comment: You have paste wrong code.`input", this).attr("checked", !x);` have no sense.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click td, select radio button in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625037/click-td-select-radio-button-in-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `.each` for all two class like:

```js
$( ".clickable" ).each(function( index ) {
  $(this).click(function(event) {
    var x = jQuery("input", this).attr("checked");
    jQuery("input", this).attr("checked", !x);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>

  <tr class="row_cls" id="quiz_row0">
    <td class="clickable" style="border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: middle;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">
      <label style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <input type="radio" style="height:20px; width:20px;" class="radio-form-control radio_input1" id="radio_input166" name="quiz_row0" value="Herausforderung" checked="checked"> 
            <span style="font-size: 20px;">Herausforderung</span>
        </label></td>
    <td class="clickable" style="border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: middle;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">
      <label style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <input type="radio" style="height:20px; width:20px;" class="radio-form-control radio_input1" id="radio_input118" name="quiz_row0" value="Macht/ Aufstieg" checked="checked"> 
            <span style="font-size: 20px;">Macht/ Aufstieg</span>
        </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

Pure js solution:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.clickable').forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    el.querySelector('input').checked = true;
  });
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="row_cls" id="quiz_row0">
    <td class="clickable" style="border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: middle;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">
      <label style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <input type="radio" style="height:20px; width:20px;" class="radio-form-control radio_input1" id="radio_input166" name="quiz_row0" value="Herausforderung" checked="checked"> 
            <span style="font-size: 20px;">Herausforderung</span>
        </label></td>
    <td class="clickable" style="border:1px solid #ddd;vertical-align: middle;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:10px;">
      <label style="margin-bottom:0px;">
            <input type="radio" style="height:20px; width:20px;" class="radio-form-control radio_input1" id="radio_input118" name="quiz_row0" value="Macht/ Aufstieg" checked="checked"> 
            <span style="font-size: 20px;">Macht/ Aufstieg</span>
        </label></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your jQuery version shows the same behaviour as mine, might be some other parts of my code that are at fault. The pure JS version works great!

Comment: Pure js is the best way always :P

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use jQuery – or JavaScript of any kind – to "make the whole cell clickable," all you have to do is use CSS to have the `<label>` element fill the whole of the cell. One approach is below, with explanatory comments in the CSS:

```css
/* copied the CSS from the relevant elements' "style"
   attribute into the CSS below: */
td.clickable {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* removed the padding from the <td> and applied
     it to the <label> child element in order that
     the <label> could extend to the edges of its
     parent <td> (this element) */
}

label {
  /* by default causes the <label> to take the full
     width of its parent: */
  display: block;
  /* removes any margin that might move the <label>
     from the edges of its parents borders: */
  margin: 0;
  /* padding applied to the <label> instead of the
     parent <td>, in order to preserve spacing
     and aesthetics, but keeping the <label>
     positioned against all edges of the parent: */
  padding-block: 10px;
  padding-inline: 10px;
}

td.clickable input {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

td.clickable span {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row_cls" id="quiz_row0">
      <!-- I moved the inline CSS from the "style" attributes into the CSS pane, on the right;
           this makes it easier to modify the design and makes the HTML easier to read and
           understand: -->
      <td class="clickable">
        <label>
          <!-- I've modified your <input> elements; in your original code they both had the
               "checked" attribute, but as they share the same "name" only one could ever
               be active, or "checked." With that in mind I removed the attribute from the
               second of <input> elements, so the first <input> is checked by default: -->
          <input type="radio" class="radio-form-control radio_input1" id="radio_input166" name="quiz_row0" value="Herausforderung" checked="checked">
          <span>Herausforderung</span>
        </label></td>
      <td class="clickable">
        <label>
          <input type="radio" class="radio-form-control radio_input1" id="radio_input118" name="quiz_row0" value="Macht/ Aufstieg">
          <span>Macht/ Aufstieg</span>
        </label></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `event.currentTarget` to make sure you always target the clickable parent row no matter the user clicks on inside the row. then use `.find()` to get the input field inside the clicked row.

```
jQuery(".clickable").on( 'click', function(event) {
    let clickable = jQuery(event.currentTarget);
    let radioInput = clickable.find('.radio_input1');
    radioInput.prop("checked", true );
});
```

Comment: not true for jQuery. The `this` is used instead, at least if not inside an arrow function.

Comment: well. It's the same thing. why not true for jQuery?
https://api.jquery.com/event.currenttarget/

Comment: Not that it's wrong, your statement is not exact. Since instead of `event.currentTarget` you can simply use simply `this`.